How can I add a student (@gmail.com) to a Classroom class created inside my organization via Apps Script?
I have admin permissions in an Google Workspace organization, and I want to invite an external user (@gmail.com) as a student in a Classroom class, using Classroom API inside Google Apps Script.
Currently I am using this code to invite any user:
Classroom.Invitations.create({
    "userId": email,
    "courseId": courseId,
    "role": "STUDENT"
  });

It works okay if the email belongs to my organization's domain, but if I try the same code with a @gmail.com account, the script returns:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.invitations.create failed with error: The caller does not have permission

I do can add it manually inside Google Classroom, but it doesn't work via Apps Script. It might be worth mentioning that the owner account of the Classroom is not my account, but another one inside my domain, and the script I'm using is inside a shared drive.
SOLVED (thanks to Saddles): For it to work, the admin account trying to invite the students must be enrolled as a teacher in the course.

possibly related

Can you confirm the admin permissions in an Google Workspace organization the account you're using currently has? From what I know, a Super Admin or a verified teacher added as a co-teacher should be able to add a consumer Google account in a Google Classroom.

This is assuming that the Who can join classes in your domain? setting of the Admin console is set to Any user because of the statement I do can add it manually inside Google Classroom, but it doesn't work via Apps Script. You may double-check this by following the help center article in the thread of @James' comment.

Yes, I do confirm that the "Who can join classes in your domain?" setting is set to "Any user", and I am "Super Admin".

Understood. The error only suggests that the cause of this is a permission issue. Can you try adding that user to the Teachers of the Google Classroom and see what happens? You may also Browse in Incognito mode since there are times that accounts switch over after going to a different page, resulting in issues like this.

Ok, I tried adding the Super Admin account as a teacher and it magically worked! No idea why it needs to be a teacher to add external students and not to add internal students. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Let me go ahead and rephrase my comments to be an answer to this question since you mentioned that it magically worked. That way, other community members who stumble upon this post may know this information. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it as well.

After some testing on a Google Workspace account, to add a @gmail.com user to a classroom using Google Apps Script, ensure that the Who can join classes in your domain? setting in the Admin console is set to Any user.
Afterwards, add the Super Admin as a co-teacher in Google Classroom since the error GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.invitations.create failed with error: The caller does not have permission shows up if not.
REFERENCE

Add a co-teacher to a class

